# UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-update, odbc

I am trying to **update** on table from another where the Primary Key for both is `trans_nbr`.

My statement is posted below. All I am getting as an error is "a syntax error has occurred". The primary key is the only link between the two tables which also contain the same amount of rows.

I was able to do it before but then I found out the sequenceID on the `brev_efile_user_doc_stats` table is different depending on how the XML was handled in the review process which is why there is a `corrected_seq_id` column in the same table.

```
UPDATE 
    brev_efile_user_doc_stats.reviewed_event_code
    , brev_efile_user_doc_stats.corrected_seq_id 
SET 
    brev_efile_user_doc_stats.reviewed_event_code
    , brev_efile_user_doc_stats.corrected_seq_id = 
        (SELECT 
            brev_efile_review.reviewed_event_code
            , brev_efile_review.sequence_id 
        FROM 
            brev_efile_review 
        WHERE 
            brev_efile_review.trans_nbr = brev_efile_user_doc_stats.trans_nbr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for :

### In SQL SERVER

```
UPDATE
    brev_efile_user_doc_stats
SET
    brev_efile_user_doc_stats.reviewed_event_code = R.reviewed_event_code
    , brev_efile_user_doc_stats.corrected_seq_id = R.sequence_id
FROM
    brev_efile_user_doc_stats S
    INNER JOIN brev_efile_review R
        ON R.trans_nbr = S.trans_nbr
```

### In Mysql

```
UPDATE brev_efile_user_doc_stats AS S
    INNER JOIN brev_efile_review AS R ON R.trans_nbr = S.trans_nbr
SET S.reviewed_event_code = R.reviewed_event_code
    , S.corrected_seq_id = R.sequence_id
```

Comment: I am doing this through an ODBC into an Informix database. My apologies for not including this before hand. I've run the answers provided and AQT is still giving me the "syntax error" problem without telling me what the issue is exactly.

Comment: I search information on google, I don't undertand what is your environement, are you coding and using ODBC to run sql statement ? Then can you show us the full code and the database stucture. Can you run this sql directly on your RDBMS ?

Comment: I was able to use your statement and get it to work. thank you for your help!